# Advantage on initiative/never surprised or double fire damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, multi-classing

I’m playing a super beefy multiclass lv6 barbarian zealot/lv9 cleric of the forge domain. I’ve come to terms with what I’ll gain and lose for the most part, but there’s one trait I’m debating.

If I gain one more level in barbarian, I gain advantage on initiative and cannot be surprised in combat.  However, if I do that I can’t reach lv14 cleric of the forge domain. And at lv14 I gain double fire damage per hit.

Should I sacrifice my fire damage for the advantage on rolls? Or should I stick it out for that sweet damage buff?

By the way, this is a lv15 startup character, and he’s an envoy warforged (I know not optimized, but I love the role-play aspect).

Comment: @SantanaAfton That sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: Which you should do is entirely a matter of opinion. We might be able to help with which one is **factually** best for a given **goal**, if you could add your goal to your question with [edit]ing. Otherwise, to just get opinions from people on the internet, you’ll want to post instead on a discussion forum (such as [one of these](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321)).